# filtering data in grid view to see latest data

Tags: vb.net

I have a table as under

```
 
____________________________________________________
|Name | DtFrom  |   DtTo     | City |  Designation  | 
____________________________________________________
|  Z  | 01/01/02 | 01/01/03 |Delhi |      ADM       |
_____________________________________________________
|  Z  | 02/01/03 | 01/01/04 |Mumbai|      ADM       |
_____________________________________________________
|  Z  | 02/01/04 | 01/01/05 |Delhi |       DM       |
_____________________________________________________
|  Z  | 02/01/05 | 01/01/06 |Delhi |       DM       |
_____________________________________________________   
|  Z  | 02/01/06 | 01/01/07 |Mumbai|       DM       |
_____________________________________________________
|  Z  | 05/01/07 | 12/12/10 |Mumbai| CDM            |
```

I want to view data-" presently where ‘Z’ is posted and since when?”  and the display should be as under:

```
         From----------To-----------City-----Designation

|  Z  | 02/01/06 | 01/01/07        |Mumbai|  DM      |
_____________________________________________________
|  Z  | 05/01/07 | 12/12/10        |Mumbai| CDM      |
_____________________________________________________
```

I am working with gridview in vb.net
Kindly help me because the query top 2 order by desc does not solve the purpose.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Query top 2 order by desc and order by asc again.

Comment: check dtTodate is null then you fill to grdiview